# param not found errror in Rails 4 app using strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've been struggling with figuring out why I'm getting the following error.  It seems as if by  virtue of there being a fruit_controller, the parameter :fruit should exist.  Any help would be much appreciated as this has been driving me up the wall for the past five hours.

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in FruitsController#new
param not found: fruit

Extracted source (around line #80):
78
79
80
81
82

    def fruit_params
      params.require(:fruit).permit(:name, :color)
    end
end

Rails.root: C:/Users/Guy/code/food-master

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:173:in `require'
app/controllers/fruits_controller.rb:80:in `fruit_params'
app/controllers/fruits_controller.rb:24:in `new'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__564231598__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1012308376__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
Request

Parameters:

{"food_id"=>"1"}
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None
```

This is fruits_controller.rb:

```
class fruitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_fruit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /fruits
  # GET /fruits.json
  def index
    @food = Food.find(params[:food_id])
    @fruits = @food.fruits.all
  end

  # GET /fruits/1
  # GET /fruits/1.json
  def show
    @fruit = fruit.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: @fruit}
    end
  end

  # GET /fruits/new
  def new
    @food = Food.find(params[:food_id])
    @fruit = @food.fruits.new(fruit_params)
  end

  # GET /fruits/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /fruits
  # POST /fruits.json
  def create
    @food = Food.find(params[:food_id])
    @fruit = @food.fruits.create(fruit_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @fruit.save
        format.html { redirect_to @fruit, notice: 'fruit was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @fruit }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @fruit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /fruits/1
  # PATCH/PUT /fruits/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @fruit.update(fruit_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @fruit, notice: 'fruit was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @fruit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /fruits/1
  # DELETE /fruits/1.json
  def destroy
    @fruit.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to fruits_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_fruit
      @fruit = fruit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def fruit_params
      params.require(:fruit).permit(:name,:color)
    end
end
```

here's fruits/index.html.erb

```
<h1>New fruit</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', food_fruit_path(@food) %>
```

and fruits/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@fruit) do |f| %>
  <% if @fruit.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@fruit.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this fruit from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @fruit.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :color %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :color, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save fruit", :class => "btn btn-success" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have no trouble with the index view, but it only happens when I try to create a new fruit from index view:

```
 <%= link_to 'New Fruit', new_food_fruit_path %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us the view.

Comment: sorry about that! I've never troubleshot full blown RoR before.  I'll get the hang of it though, hopefully!

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because you're calling `fruit_params` in the `new` action. You should only `build` objects in the `new` action so that they're prepared for the form.

This is the code that you have now:

```
@fruit = @food.fruits.new(fruit_params)
```

Which is almost functional... the only problem is the `fruit_params` call, which expects `params[:fruit]` to be available, but it isn't because you're making a request to that path using this helper:

```
<%= link_to 'New Fruit', new_food_fruit_path %>
```

There are no parameters being passed there, so `params[:fruit]` is going to be absent in your `new` action.

Change your `new` action's code to this:

```
def new
  @food = Food.find(params[:food_id])
  @fruit = @food.fruits.new
end
```

This will setup the `@fruit` variable to be used in the form at `app/views/fruits/_form.html.erb`.

Comment: thank you for your response!  I had followed your advice and I think I'm understanding what 'new' does with your explanation.  It also looks like I'm getting closer but now I'm getting a different error message as follows:
`NoMethodError in FruitsController#new
undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
  def new
    @food = Food.find(params[:food_id])
    @fruit = @food.fruits.build
  end`